# Read arguments from command line and act on certain value

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve the following exercise :

> **Command Line Arguments** To demonstrate your mastery over command line argument passing, your program should:
>
> 1. Accept a character as an argument into main.
> 2. Print out a message if the character is '1' otherwise
> 3. Print out the character

I have problem with ad in main.c, I cannot run with ad=1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    if (ad=1)
     printf("xx");
    else if
     printf("%ad");

    return;
}

main();
```

The compiler outputs the following errors :

```
test.c:5:9: error: ‘ad’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:5:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once
            for each function it appears in
test.c:8:6: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘printf’
test.c:8:6: warning: format ‘%a’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat=]
test.c: At top level:
test.c:13:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
test.c:13:1: error: conflicting types for ‘main’
test.c:3:6: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
```

Comment: You need to disable your ad blocker.

Comment: I just saw this hot meta post appear as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312052/canonical-question-for-typo-for?cb=1

Comment: @Tas that's far from the only error though...

Comment: Oh yeah I know! **far** from the only error.

Comment: can you help me fix error? kind regards, Jahmal

Comment: Honestly, and the reason I downvoted, is that there is **so** much wrong here I get the impression you not only don't know C++, you've made no effort to attempt to learn it or solve the issue yourself. I mean, the compiler would point out half your mistakes: you'd fix most of this code by **reading what the compiler was telling you were the errors**.

Comment: I am writing program for master's education. I do not understand error which is why I come here. kind regards, Jahmal

Comment: I am just trying to run ad=1 with main

Comment: @Jahmal It's obvious you have not even learnt the basics of the language (not sure how you will go with trying to teach it). So what we are suggesting is that you get a basic C book or tutorial and learn it systematically. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site and it is not the right place to teach basic language concepts that you can learn elsewhere.

Comment: Show your errors and we probably can help you.

Comment: Apart from the errors, we're not clear on what "run ad=1 with main" means. Since this is homework, could you post the corresponding instructions ?

Comment: test.c:5:9: error: ‘ad’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (ad=1)
         ^
test.c:5:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test.c:8:6: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘printf’
      printf("%ad");
      ^
test.c:8:6: warning: format ‘%a’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat=]
test.c: At top level:
test.c:13:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 main();
 ^
test.c:13:1: error: conflicting types for ‘main’
test.c:3:6: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
 void main(){

Comment: Command Line Arguments

To demonstrate your mastery over command line argument passing, your program should:

1. Accept a character as an argument into main.
2. Print out a message if the character is '1' otherwise
3. Print out the character

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work.

Comment: @Jahmal Editing additional information into the question is preferred over comments, due to their formatting limits and short life. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should come near to how your program is supposed to look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if( argc > 1 ) {
        printf( "You passed (at least) one parameter, let's see if we can handle that\n");

        if( strcmp( argv[1], "1") == 0 ) {
            printf( "Oh yes, it's a boy ! Ahem a one !\n");
        } else {
            printf( "%s\n", argv[1]);
        }
    } else {
        printf( "There is nothing we can work with\n");
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bd0a904d9a9e6d2

As your homework perhaps is to only support a single character the final touch might be missing. I will leave this up to you.

Besides missing curly braces (`{` and `}`) your code has several problems, I mention some:

```
if (ad=1)
```

You never assigned `ad` anywhere. And instead of a comparison (`==`) you made an assignment (`=`). If you wanted to compare a character `== '1'` would have been the way to go.

```
printf("%ad");
```

This is an invalid format specifier, `%d` would be valid for an `int` and `%c` for a character

Comment: doesnt work, always prints out xx. kind regards, Jahmal

Comment: @Jahmal I adjusted my answer after you provided more details, have a look